# Как с помощью jquery при клике получить id нажатой строки и отправить запрос на api подобное

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<html>
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="tbUser">
<tr><th>id</th><th>Location</th><th></th></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Ghatkopar</td><td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Powai</td><td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>Powai</td><td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>NewYork</td><td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td></tr>
</table> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#tbUser").on('click','.btnDelete',function(){
     
        var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('th').eq(0).text();
        console.log(id);
       $(this).closest('tr').remove();
     });

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Мне как сделать jquery при нажатии на кнопку отправился id той строки на которую нажал и этот id отправился на сервер id находится в таблице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $("#tbUser").on('click','.btnDelete',function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  // отправить id
});
```

```js
$("#tbUser").on('click', '.btnDelete', function() {
  var id = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text();
  console.log(id);
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbUser">
  <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Location</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Ghatkopar</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Powai</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>Powai</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>NewYork</td>
    <td><button class="btnDelete">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Он ничего не возвращает, хоть я поправил fing на td

Comment: @Sasha Опечатка.

Comment: Не скорей моя вена с версией jquery/3.4.1

Comment: Не подскажешь странную разницу с 3.4.1и 3.3.1

Comment: @Sasha Здесь работает и с 3.4.1

Comment: С моей ссылкой нет jq

Comment: @Sasha работает

Comment: Но странно у меня в консоле не пишет не подскажешь что не так? в браузере

Comment: @Sasha Если Вы имеете в виду код в вопросе, то у Вас там `.find('th')`, а нужно `.find('td')`.

Comment: я имею веду что при подключении моей библиотеки оно не пишет в  личную консоль браузера, а при вашей пишет

Comment: @Sasha Я изменил ссылку на jq.